# Google Analytics Tracking Isn't Working

Tags: button, google-analytics, analytics, tracking, event-tracking

I'd like to track the clicks on a button in my GA. I've tried searching around, but I can't seem to find anything that is helping.

Here is the code I've copied:

```
<script>
var downloadLink = document.getElementById('button');
addListener(downloadLink, 'click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'contact-button');
});


/**
 * Utility to wrap the different behaviors between W3C-compliant browsers
 * and IE when adding event handlers.
 *
 * @param {Object} element Object on which to attach the event listener.
 * @param {string} type A string representing the event type to listen for
 *     (e.g. load, click, etc.).
 * @param {function()} callback The function that receives the notification.
 */
function addListener(element, type, callback) {
 if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
 else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
}
</script>
```

And the button I'd like to track:

```
<div id="button" class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns foot-btn">
   <a href="/contact" alt="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

I tried `<a id="button" href="/contact" alt="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>` but that didn't show any results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition for "addListener" is happening after you are calling it. You need to move that definition to come before actually using it.

```
function addListener(element, type, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
    else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
}
```

and then

```
var downloadLink = document.getElementById('button');
addListener(downloadLink, 'click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'contact-button');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I need to move "id=button" to the a tag or will it still track on the div?

Comment: This isn't true. Functions are hoisted to the top of their scope, so changing the order will not make any difference.

Comment: Thanks, Philip. Any solution as to why this isn't working then?